# Can't Access Joomla HTML or CSS Code

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm attempting to change the template HTML code of my website, but when I pull up the index.php file, it displays different code than when I view the source code on my page. I need to know how to access the source code. I can't seem to change any CSS either. When I edit the template.css file, nothing changes on my page. I've tried a variety or selectors and multiple approaches but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Which Joomla version is yours? Is Joomla system cache enabled? Did you clear browser's cache? Are you editing administrator index instead of site index, or viceversa? Are you editing the active template?

Comment: 3.6.5, cache is enabled, the template is active. I will have to confirm administrator index

Comment: Please look at this link https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Modifying_a_Joomla!_Template. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

May I advise you to use a debugger. Something like Firebug if you use Firefox (or the Web Dev. Tools of Firefox `Ctrl + Shift + I`). It will show you the true path to the files (rightmost column, put the mouse on the file names), their content and you will even be able to modify them on the fly. And yes, avoid caches for debugging.